# Object has no attribute. Attribute Error: 'FoodSpawner' object has no attribure 'isFoodOnScreen'

Tags: python, pygame

We are trying to run a `pygame` program but get an `AttributeError`.  This is the error message we get and the error they say is on line 78 in the Food Spawner Class.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\lchs-file01\staff$\Tyson.Friesen\SYSTEM\Desktop\Python Junk File.py", line 120, in <module>
    food_position = food_spawner.spawn_food()
  File "\\lchs-file01\staff$\Tyson.Friesen\SYSTEM\Desktop\Python Junk File.py", line 78, in spawn_food
    if self.isFoodOnScreen == False:
AttributeError: 'FoodSpawner' object has no attribute 'isFoodOnScreen'
```

This is the code we are trying to run and we are slightly new to `pygame` so detailed help would be great. Thanks.

```
class FoodSpawner():
   #----------------------sets the food to spawn randomly
    def __init__(self):
        self.position = [random.randrange(1,50)*10], [random.randrange(1,50)*10]
        self.is_food_on_screen = True
   #----------------------
   #----------------------resets food if it spawns of screen
    def spawn_food(self):
        if self.isFoodOnScreen == False:
            self.position = [random.randrange(1,50)*10], [random.randrange(1,50)*10]
            self.is_food_on_screen = True
        return self.position
   #----------------------
    def set_food_on_screen(self,b):
        self.isFoodOnSceen = b
```

Comment: @aws_apprentice, It looks like the `__init__` method does instantiate the attribute: `self.is_food_on_screen = True`

Comment: `isFoodOnScreen` has to be `is_food_on_screen`

Comment: @ColinMac whoops you're right, they are both named the same and one is capital and the other isn't which got me confused

Comment: @aws_apprentice... turns out you were right... they didn't technically make the property in the `__init__`, name was wrong, like you said.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, you're setting the attribute `self.is_food_on_screen = True` in `__init__` and trying to access `self.isFoodOnScreen` which is only set in `set_food_on_screen`

If you call `spawn_food` before `set_food_on_screen` then you will hit this exception because `self.isFoodOnScreen` won't exist as an instance attribute yet.

Seems like you want to be using `self.is_food_on_screen` wherever you are using `self.isFoodOnScreen`

Answer (score 1):

You created self.is_food_on_screen = True in your `__init__` method,

...

and then tried to set isFoodOnScreen (in camel-case, instead of with underscores)...

I suspect your error will go away if you make the names the same.

Comment: I would also suggest learning to format code in your questions.  You can read about that here, it's quite easy: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks